# Bean property being set to 0

Tags: java, jsf

My bean is correctly using a setter and sets the property to the desired value, but then it enters into a method which uses the property and it is automatically being set to 0. I don't even know where the 0 is coming from. In debug it jumps right from the setter to the method so I cannot see anything happening in-between.

The bean uses the `@SessionScoped` annotation if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What is the type of property?

Comment: so its being set to its default value 0

Comment: Does it automatically default to 0? If that's the case then yes.

Comment: Yes it defaults the member variable with its default value

Comment: Any idea how to stop it from resetting?

Comment: it should remain unchanged, what import you made for @SessionScoped ?

Comment: import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

Comment: changing to import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; solved the problem. Please make an answer and I will select you as best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> *private int vendorno*

Java primitives like `int`, `boolean`, `long`, etc have a fixed default value.

Use wrapper objects instead like `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Long`. They can be `null`.

```
private Integer vendorno;
```

#### See also:

- [Learning the Java Language > Language Basics > Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)